# Magento2: Product tabs

Tags: magento2, product-tab

I changed location product tabs. In first tab I added "Custom tab (oferty)".
But when I open product then first is displayed szczegóły (en: details).

Any one know how to display first after open product page first tab "oferty" ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit or create your custom

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And add order priority  attribute to blocks

```
<arguments> <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument> </arguments>
```

If this not work try with this outside product.info.details

Use reference container

```
<referenceBlock name="szczegoly" template="product/view/custom_template.phtml" > <arguments><argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument></arguments> </referenceBlock>  <referenceBlock name="oferty" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" > <arguments><argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument></arguments> </referenceBlock>
```